# Page out large memory block in Linux

Tags: c++, linux, memory, memory-management

I want to allocate a large vector, e.g., 1 or 2GB. Use it for a while and then page it out. And then bring it back when I needed to touch some areas.

In Windows I would probably create a mapped file (backed by ssd/nvme)

What are the libraries that in Linux (ubuntu/centos) to do these sort of things?

Comment: If a mapped file is what you want, then you can do that in Linux systems as well.

Comment: Why do you want to manually "page it out"? The operating system will do this automatically for pages that haven't been used for a long time and replace them with more recently used pages. It will also automatically page in your file again once you start using it again, provided there is sufficient physical memory available.

Comment: You can create a mapped file using `mmap`.  And for any block of memory, whether backed by a file or the system's swap space, you can call `madvise` to tell the system when you do or don't need it.  These are in the standard C library.

Comment: Thank you all. I will try first madvise, it is the closest to what I need. I'll try mmap next.